# jquery target blank is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know, the title is a bit misleading, but:

I am getting a resource from outside and I am feeding my page with this it, like news, videos, etc.

Now, all links in those feeds are not 'target_blank'ed, I tried to make all links `target="_blank"` in this way:

```
$(function(){
  $('.newstext').find('a').attr('target','_blank');
});
```

But the links are still opening in the same tab.

The code of a link looks like this (after I added target_blank with jQuery):

```
<a href="someurl" rel="nofollow" onclick="spotonTrackOutboundLink(this.href); return false;" target="_blank">
   some text about this link
</a>
```

Why is it still opening in the same tab? Am I missing something? is it because of `return false;` ?

Comment: What is the logic inside spotonTrackOutboundLink

Comment: Have you tried: `.prop('target','_blank');` instead?

Comment: UM, first that link you showed will not open up a page because you cancel the click action [unless there is a js error].

Comment: @MelanciaUK yap, ``prop`` and ``attr`` do the same job here.

Comment: @epascarello — The only class selector applies to an ancestor of the link.

Comment: You are going to need to show what is in `spotonTrackOutboundLink` since the way it is coded now should work fine.

Comment: @Quentin Ah you caught me before I tried to ninja edit it. :) Morning coffee did not kick in. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The link will only be followed if `spotonTrackOutboundLink` throws an error or JavaScript is disabled.

Presumably `spotonTrackOutboundLink` is redirecting the browser. You'll need to find that code and (perhaps conditionally) switch it to use `window.open()`.

Comment: yap, i found the function code, it does this in callback: 
``{"hitCallback":function () {document.location = url;}}`` where ``url`` is ``this.href``. I think, I have to live with this since i cannot change the code. thank you anyway

Answer (score 1):

just open the window with your Javascript method that is being called.

```
function spotonTrackOutboundLink(url) {
  var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
  win.focus();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by : `onclick="spotonTrackOutboundLink(this.href); return false;"`

Remove `return false;` from there and should work fine.

Comment: [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vc0uxkdf/) that demonstrates the difference in behavior.

Comment: @AndréDion yeah, and removing return false is working fine here http://jsfiddle.net/vc0uxkdf/1/

Comment: That fiddle makes no sense. It is impossible to give an answer without knowing what is in `spotonTrackOutboundLink`

Comment: the function is opening the link but preventing it using return false, that's it. Nothing else...

Comment: It would not cause it to ignore the _blank. From what the OP said, the link is working, it is just opening in the same tab. It is not ignoring the click.

Comment: It obviously cause to not to open in new window... Please see @Andre and my jsfiddle for comparison..

Comment: As stated in the comment it has nothing to do with the return false, it has to do with the function called.